# Toggle Visibility Driver Not Working

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

I have a driver which toggles the visibility of a mesh.
If I set the driver the scripted expression and type in "True" when the visibility is off, the visibility turns on.
If the visibility is already on and I type in "False", the visibility does not change.

Comment: Share your blend file, see  https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/344/888

Comment: Use`int` for boolean drivers .. eg `1 if var > 39.9 else 0` will set the driver to `True` if some driver variable is greater than `39.9` else `False`  Editing the scripted expression to be either `True` or `False` isn't really the concept behind drivers.

Comment: I was using inequalities for my driver, but for simplicity, I changed the values to True and False while testing whether or not the driver works the way I thought it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing in "False" makes the object visible and typing in "True" hides the object.